# create a whitelabel website and point domains to it

Tags: iis-7, web, domain-name, white-labelling

I'm after a little advice. I have a few websites which all essentially serve the same content. I have say websiteA, websiteB and websiteC. Each one points to one database to serve the content (think of it as a dating website). Each website has a folder in wwwroot and is mapped to the relevant domain name.

What I'd like to be able to do is have one website, say website A and simply point each of the domain names to that one site. However, how would I then make each site look different? Do I need something within websiteA which say if the referring URL is websiteB.com - serve this style sheet... if the website referring is WebsiteC.com then serve this CSS.

I suppose it's like creating a whitelabel service? I just don't know where I'd start!

Many thanks.

(PS: We have a windows dedicated server with IIS7)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be to react to the HTTP_HOST header, which will tell you which website the request if for, even if they're all mapped to the same folder.